# How can I make my .net command-line exe accept img%03d.png?

Tags: vb.net

Command line programs like ffmpeg.exe accept a parameter like so:

```
c:\> ffmpeg.exe -i img%03d.png img.gif
```

This will grab all these images in the directory and use them inside the program:

```
img001.png
img002.png
img003.png
img004.png
```

Is there a clever way to implement this in my VB.net command line project, or do I have to parse the argument for the %0?

Comment: And by clever way you are asking for the code?? %03d looks like a regex, so why not just compare it to a list of files in a folder?? that's clever enough?

Comment: I was not aware % is a special character in RegEx. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It doesn't matter if that is a spec char or not (that I don't remember :) ) I mean, that you can just filter a folder files list using regex to get all the files that match your need...

Answer (score 1):

You might try using quotes, like this:

ffmpeg.exe -i "img 3.png" "img.gif".   I've used quotes before to get around spaces in parameters (like changing directories in DOS).

Comment: I think that is that is just only an example. OP looks like asking how to accomplish that easily?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my example. I want to pass one parameter into a command line executable that I am creating in VB.net that means "all these files that have a zero padded number at the end"